# Extract number from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have string in the bellow format:

> let str = "url(#123456)";

My string have only number contain in it. It can be any where.
I want to extract the number `123456` from the above string.

I am using es6.

Comment: Use a regex. Use https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`

```js
let str = "url(#123456)";
console.log(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''))
```

Comment: better to mark as duplicate, right?

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it

```
let str = "url(#123456)";

console.log(str.match(/\d+/)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in a way too complicated way, but it does not involve regex so it's probably better to understand:

```js
let str = "url(#123456)";
str = str.split("#");
str = str[1].split(")");
str = str[0];
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only Array methods:

```js
console.log("url(#123456)".split('#').pop().slice(0, this.length -1))
```